# link is not working in chrome Version 37.0.2062.124 m

Tags: wordpress, browser

I'm in the end of a project and right top navigation link don't work in chrome.

When you click on them nothing happens

This is the website http://hambastuudio.ee/hambaarst/

Comment: not working in right side text under image 
VAHETA LEHTE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add these lines to the css

```
.header-img {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 9000;
}
```